# Excluding multiple directories not working as expected with robocopy

Tags: robocopy

I'm running the command:

```
robocopy /E /XJD E: D: /XD 'E:\$RECYCLE.BIN\' 'E:\System Volume Information\'
```

Which runs for a while but then gets stuck at:

```
2022/05/21 21:39:04 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying File E:\System Volume Information\tracking.log
Access is denied.
Waiting 30 seconds...
```

I think I'm using the right syntax for multiple directory exclusion, but just in case I tried:

```
robocopy /E /XJD E: D: /XD 'E:\System Volume Information\' /XD 'E:\$RECYCLE.BIN\' 'E:\System Volume Information\'
```

This errors with the same message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please try `/XD 'E:\System Volume Information\' /s` to exclude the sub directories.

Comment: And you might need to use double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'` as well

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks but no change I'm afraid. Here's my modified command: `robocopy E: D: /E /XJD /XD "E:\System Volume Information\" "E:\$RECYCLE.BIN\" /s`

Comment: Hmm. `/XD "c:\System Volume Information" /S` is from [Robocopy "Robust File Copy" - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

Comment: Are you running as an Administrator?

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes I'm running from an elevated powershell prompt

Comment: Then I'm stumped :/

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for trying! It's a one off so I'll just use explorer :)

Comment: Try this command robocopy /E /XJD E: D: /XD  "$RECYCLE.BIN" "System Volume Information" /S  Do not specify the Drive Letter. I tried it on a sample setup and seems it is working. Don't know exactly how. Give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

For others checking this, it doesn't seem to like the $ sign in $RECYCLE.BIN when I was running it in Powershell so I had to escape that with a backtick:

```
robocopy /E /XJD E: D: /XD "`$RECYCLE.BIN" "System Volume Information"
```